# Get last 4 weeks records by day grouped by weeks

Tags: php, mysql

I require a query that will allow me to select the last 4 weeks worth of data from a MySQL table however output as days starting from Monday 4 weeks ago regardless of the current day of the week.

The DB has a user table, an activities tables which has a FK of userID. 
An activityStats table with a FK to activityID

The query will be used to create an array similar to:

```
$array = [
   "userid" => "userid",
   "dateAdded" => "dateAdded",
   "week1" => $array = [
      "monday" => $array = [
         "activityid" => "1",
         "time" => "21",
         ...
      ]
      "tuesday" => $array = [
         "activityid" => "2",
         "time" => "16",
         ...
      ]
      "wednesday" => $array = [
         "activityid" => "3",
         "time" => "16",
         ...
      ]
      ...
   "week2" => $array = [
      "monday" => $array = [
         "activityid" => "8",
         "time" => "21",
         ...
      ]
      "tuesday" => $array = [
         "activityid" => "9",
         "time" => "16",
         ...
      ]
      "wednesday" => $array = [
         "activityid" => "10",
         "time" => "16",
         ...
      ]
      ...
   ]
   ...
];
```

I could create multiple queries which would do the trick but there could be a requirement to get 10 weeks, or 52 weeks and separate queries might not cut it.

Don't know where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your timestamp column is called `timestamp`, you can:

`SELECT CONCAT(YEAR(timestamp), '/', WEEK(timestamp)) AS week`

and then retrieve specific ranges, order by week, etc.